# Llamar una url de una imagen de JSON a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

En los datos de mi json de wordpress tengo lo siguiente:

```
 [
{
id: 10033,
title: {
rendered: "My title"
},
content: {
rendered: "Sample text html",
}
_embedded: {
wp:featuredmedia: [
{
source_url: "https://domain.com/myimage.jpg",
}
]
}
}
```

Tengo mis estructuras en el archivo OfertasData.swift

```
struct JsonSosTalleres : Codable {
    let id : Int
    let title : Title?
    let content : Content?
    let embedded : Embedded?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case title = "title"
        case content = "content"
        case embedded = "_embedded"
    }

}


struct Title : Codable {
    let rendered : String?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case rendered = "rendered"
    }
}

struct Content : Codable {
    let rendered : String?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case rendered = "rendered"
    }
}


struct Embedded : Codable {
    let featuredmedia : [Featuredmedia]?    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case featuredmedia = "wp:featuredmedia"
    }
}

struct Featuredmedia : Codable {
    let urlimage : String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case urlimage = "source_url"
    }
}
```

Todos estos datos lo quiero pasar a una UITableView usando JSON Decodable, obtengo el titulo correctamente en la tabla pero tengo problemas para llamar a la url de la imagen:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



        guard let cell = tablaOfertas.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ofertacell") as? OfertasTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        cell.tituloPost.text = datosOfertas[indexPath.row].title?.rendered // funciona ok

        cell.imagePost.text = datosOfertas[indexPath.row].embedded?.featuredmedia?.urlimage // error :  Value of type '[Featuredmedia]' has no member 'urlimage'

        return cell

    }
```

Alguna sugerencia de por que no funciona o como llamaría a la URL de la imagen?

El titulo si me coge corrcetamente, pero con el código este código para a iamgen:

`cell.imagePost.text = datosOfertas[indexPath.row].embedded?.featuredmedia?.urlimage`

```
me dice: Value of type '[Featuredmedia]' has no member 'urlimage'
```

Comment: Estas llamando el arreglo de tipo Featuredmedia de la clase Embedded que es un arreglo que contiene objetos del tipo Featuredmedia dentro, por eso te dice que no tiene un miembro con ese nombre. Primero debes obtener un objeto del arreglo y entonces sí acceder al urlImage.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solucionado:

```
cell.imagePost.text = datosOfertas[indexPath.row].embedded?.featuredmedia?[0].urlimage
```

Comment: Hola Mario Burga, me alegra que hayas podido encontrar una respuesta y que la hayas compartido con la comunidad. Sería ideal si pudieras añadir una pequeña descripción de cuál era el problema en concreto y cómo el código de la respuesta lo solucionó. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

```
_embedded: {
wp:featuredmedia: **[**
{
 source_url: 
"https://domain.com/
myimage.jpg",
}
**]**
 }
}
```

Los corchetes que tienes en tu JSON indica que es un arreglo y tu primer elemento tiene el valor que buscas en swift 4 quedaria asi...

```
cell.imagePost.text = datosOfertas[indexPath.row].embedded?.featuredmedia?.first.urlimage
```

Aunque no si lo que quieres es cargar la imagen en una UIImageView debes de usar ese url para descargar la imagen...

```
let urlString = datosOfertas[indexPath.row].embedded?.featuredmedia?.first.urlimage
let url = URL(string: urlString)
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) // asegurate que la imagen existe en este url, si no, has unwrap y usa try/catch

imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```